# Overwriting nested styles in React Bootstrap using Styled-Components

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I'm using styled-components with React Bootstrap. We want a tab (Tab 3 in this example) to be colored based on a status. It works well when the tab is not active, but when it's active, the Bootstrap style overwrites the style.

I've identified the style that's overwriting my color in the console. When I use console to turn off the style, I see my intended tab color.

I'm just not sure how to target this style using style-components. I've tried experimenting with different ideas from the official [doc](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#can-i-nest-rules) but haven't been able to get it working.

My styled component:

```
 export const TabNavItem = styled(NavItem)`
      background-color: ${props => (props.colorize ? 'orange' : 'white')};
      }
    `;
```

Usage:

```
  render() {
    const { children, active, colorize } = this.props;
    return (
      <TabNavItem onClick={this.handleChangeLocation} active={active} colorize={colorize}>
        {children}
      </TabNavItem>
    );
  }
```

Color works fine when tab is not active:

[image: Color works fine when tab is not active]

When tab is active, color is covered by Bootstrap styles:

[image: When tab is active, color is covered by Bootstrap styles]

This is the style I need to overwrite (background-color):

[image: This is the style I need to overwrite (background-color)]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I typically wouldn't apply `styled-components` directly to each `react-bootstrap` components, but instead create a single one to wrap the entire component scope and rely more on CSS classes to get things done.

For example in your case, I would do something like:

```js
const StyledWrap = styled.div`
  & .nav-tabs > .active > li {
    background: white;
  }

  & .nav-tabs > .active.colorize > li {
    background: orange;
  }
`
const MyCustomNavbar = (props) => {
  return (
    <StyledWrap>
      /* ... */
        <NavItem active={true} />
        <NavItem className="colorize"/>
        <NavItem active={true} className="colorize" />
      /* ... */
    </StyledWrap>
  )
}
```

In my opinion, its a cleaner pattern that keeps your component specific CSS properly scoped, concentrated and comprehensive.

Generally, I find that applying `styled-components` only once per component scope keeps things simple and manageable. When you apply it in multiple places you end up doing a lot of prefixing and end up with code that looks like this:

```
<StyledNavbar>
  <StyledNav>
    <StyledNavItem active={true} />
    <StyledNavDropdown>
      <StyledMenuItem eventKey={1.1}>Action 1</StyledMenuItem>
      <StyledMenuItem eventKey={1.2}>Action 2</StyledMenuItem>
    </StyledNavDropdown>
  </StyledNav>
</StyledNavbar>
```

This is an extreme example, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of suggestions for how you might be able to fix this particular issue. You might not like either of them, as they aren't very *elegant*, but here goes.

### Approach 1

Override the style using a more specific selector. You know how styled components can leverage Sass to their advantage? Well, you can use that to create a selector for your tabs that will be at least as specific as the one in Bootstrap. Assuming the component you are styling is the `li` in this equation, you could do something like this (hacky, I know).

```
body .nav-tabs > & {
    &.active > a {
        background-color: blue; // whatever
    }
}
```

The initial `&` refers of course to the `li` in question, so would give you a selector like `body .nav-tabs > li.active > a`

### Approach 2

A little bit simpler would be the idea of using the `!important` flag at the end of the CSS rule, like so:

```
export const TabNavItem = styled(NavItem)`
  background-color: ${props => (props.colorize ? 'orange' : 'white')} !important;
`;
```